# Select top 10 records for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, greatest-n-per-group

I want to return top 10 records from each section in one query. Can anyone help with how to do it?  Section is one of the columns in the table.

Database is SQL Server 2005. I want to return the top 10 by date entered.  Sections are business, local, and feature.  For one particular date I want only the top (10) business rows (most recent entry), the top (10) local rows, and the top (10) features.

Answer (score 277):

If you are using SQL 2005 you can do something like this...

```
SELECT rs.Field1,rs.Field2 
    FROM (
        SELECT Field1,Field2, Rank() 
          over (Partition BY Section
                ORDER BY RankCriteria DESC ) AS Rank
        FROM table
        ) rs WHERE Rank <= 10
```

If your RankCriteria has ties then you may return more than 10 rows and Matt's solution may be better for you.

Comment: If you really just want the top 10, change it to RowNumber() instead of Rank().  No ties then.

Comment: This works, but be aware that rank() is likely to be turned into a full table sort by the query planner if there isn't an index who's *first* key is the RankCriteria. In this case you may get better mileage selecting the distinct sections and cross applying to pick out the top 10 ordered by RankCriteria desc.

Comment: Great Answer! Got me almost exactly what I needed. I ended up going with `DENSE_RANK` which doesn't have any gaps in numbering. +1

Comment: "FROM table ) rs WHERE Rank <= 10)" what is this 'rs' thing

Comment: @Facbed It's just an alias on the table.

Comment: For anyone using Sql Server, the RowNumber() function mentioned by Mike L is ROW_NUMBER().

Answer (score 128):

In T-SQL, I would do:

```
WITH TOPTEN AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    over (
        PARTITION BY [group_by_field] 
        order by [prioritise_field]
    ) AS RowNo 
    FROM [table_name]
)
SELECT * FROM TOPTEN WHERE RowNo <= 10
```

Comment: :Please be more descriptive about your solution. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: Is select query at CTE can contain where clause?

Comment: @toha Yes it can

Comment: Although you say "In T-SQL" this works for any database implementing the `ROW_NUMBER` function. For example, I've used this solution in SQLite.

Comment: It works for postgres sql as well. I just had to use "order by [prioritise_field] desc "

Comment: you are adding a row number to each distinct `[group_by_field]` in the order of `[prioritise_field]`. These row numbers are then used to filter out rows in the outer query.

Answer (score 47):

```
SELECT r.*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        r.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.[SectionID]
                          ORDER BY r.[DateEntered] DESC) rn
    FROM [Records] r
) r
WHERE r.rn <= 10
ORDER BY r.[DateEntered] DESC
```

Comment: What if there is a tie in DateEntered?

Comment: @Yiping Undefined. Any row could win. It depends on many circumstances and can vary. You can make the order be more specific by adding more columns, e.g. `ORDER BY r.DateEntered, r.ID`, but it's all up to your particular task.

Comment: Thx, I think use RANK() in your answer will make it work.

Comment: @Yiping question was about top 10 rows from each category, RANK() could produce more. But if you need top 10 ties, RANK() definitely would be the best option.

Comment: rank()  and dense_rank()   was a bad idea,  in my case using rank or dense_rank returned 15 rows, not 10.   but when I used row_number() it always returned up to 10 rows only - correctly.  you have my vote for this best answer for my needs, similar to OP

Answer (score 35):

This works on SQL Server 2005 (edited to reflect your clarification):

```
select *
from Things t
where t.ThingID in (
    select top 10 ThingID
    from Things tt
    where tt.Section = t.Section and tt.ThingDate = @Date
    order by tt.DateEntered desc
    )
    and t.ThingDate = @Date
order by Section, DateEntered desc
```

Comment: This doesn't work for rows where Section is null, though. You'd need to say "where (tt.Section is null and t.Section is null) or tt.Section = t.Section"

Answer (score 19):

I do it this way:

```
SELECT a.* FROM articles AS a
  LEFT JOIN articles AS a2 
    ON a.section = a2.section AND a.article_date <= a2.article_date
GROUP BY a.article_id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 10;
```

---

**update:**  This example of GROUP BY works in MySQL and SQLite only, because those databases are more permissive than standard SQL regarding GROUP BY.  Most SQL implementations require that all columns in the select-list that aren't part of an aggregate expression are also in the GROUP BY.

Comment: Does that work? I'm pretty sure you'd "a.somecolumn is invalid in the select list as it is not contained in an aggregate function or the group by clause" for every column in articles except article_id..

Comment: You should be able to include other columns that are functionally dependent on the column(s) named in the GROUP BY.  Columns that are not functionally dependent are ambiguous.  But you're right, depending on RDBMS implementation.  It works in MySQL but IIRC fails in InterBase/Firebird.

Comment: Would this work in the case that the top eleven records for a section all had the same date? They would all have counts of 11 and the result would be an empty set.

Comment: No, you need to have some way of breaking ties if they all have the same date. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column/123481#123481 for an example.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks! Do you know if there's a way to do it when an article belongs to more than 1 section. For example, referring to the original question, an article about a local business might be classified under both "local" and "business" sections.

Comment: @carlosgg, if articles have a many-to-many relationship with sections, then you'd need to have an intersection table to map articles to their sections. Then your query would have to join to an intersection table for the m2m relationship, and group by article_id and section. That should get you started, but I'm not going to write out the whole solution in a comment.

Answer (score 18):

If we use SQL Server >= 2005, then we can solve the task with one *select* only:

```
declare @t table (
    Id      int ,
    Section int,
    Moment  date
);

insert into @t values
(   1   ,   1   , '2014-01-01'),
(   2   ,   1   , '2014-01-02'),
(   3   ,   1   , '2014-01-03'),
(   4   ,   1   , '2014-01-04'),
(   5   ,   1   , '2014-01-05'),

(   6   ,   2   , '2014-02-06'),
(   7   ,   2   , '2014-02-07'),
(   8   ,   2   , '2014-02-08'),
(   9   ,   2   , '2014-02-09'),
(   10  ,   2   , '2014-02-10'),

(   11  ,   3   , '2014-03-11'),
(   12  ,   3   , '2014-03-12'),
(   13  ,   3   , '2014-03-13'),
(   14  ,   3   , '2014-03-14'),
(   15  ,   3   , '2014-03-15');


-- TWO earliest records in each Section

select top 1 with ties
    Id, Section, Moment 
from
    @t
order by 
    case 
        when row_number() over(partition by Section order by Moment) <= 2 
        then 0 
        else 1 
    end;


-- THREE earliest records in each Section

select top 1 with ties
    Id, Section, Moment 
from
    @t
order by 
    case 
        when row_number() over(partition by Section order by Moment) <= 3 
        then 0 
        else 1 
    end;


-- three LATEST records in each Section

select top 1 with ties
    Id, Section, Moment 
from
    @t
order by 
    case 
        when row_number() over(partition by Section order by Moment desc) <= 3 
        then 0 
        else 1 
    end;
```

Comment: +1 I like this solution for it's simplicity but could you explain how using `top 1` works with the `case` statement in the `order by` clause returning 0 or 1?

Comment: TOP 1 works with WITH TIES here. WITH TIES means that when ORDER BY = 0, then SELECT takes this record (because of TOP 1) and all others that have ORDER BY = 0  (because of WITH TIES)

Answer (score 15):

If you know what the sections are, you can do:

```
select top 10 * from table where section=1
union
select top 10 * from table where section=2
union
select top 10 * from table where section=3
```

Comment: This would be the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: But this would be inefficient if you have 150 or if categories are variable  by day, week, etc.

Comment: Sure, but to quote OP: "Sections are business, local, and feature". If you have three static categories, this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 9):

I know this thread is a little bit old but I've just bumped into a similar problem (select the newest article from each category) and this is the solution I came up with :

```
WITH [TopCategoryArticles] AS (
    SELECT 
        [ArticleID],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [ArticleCategoryID]
            ORDER BY [ArticleDate] DESC
        ) AS [Order]
    FROM [dbo].[Articles]
)
SELECT [Articles].* 
FROM 
    [TopCategoryArticles] LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Articles] ON
        [TopCategoryArticles].[ArticleID] = [Articles].[ArticleID]
WHERE [TopCategoryArticles].[Order] = 1
```

This is very similar to Darrel's solution but overcomes the RANK problem that might return more rows than intended.

Comment: Why use CTE Sir? Is it reduce memory consumption?

Comment: @toha because CTEs are simpler and easier to understand

Comment: Great answer!! It could be optimised by using inner `JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`, since there will never be a record for `TopCategoryArticles` without a corresponding `Article` record.

Answer (score 9):

Tried the following and it worked with ties too.

```
SELECT rs.Field1,rs.Field2 
FROM (
    SELECT Field1,Field2, ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (Partition BY Section
            ORDER BY RankCriteria DESC ) AS Rank
    FROM table
    ) rs WHERE Rank <= 10
```

Comment: Hello there, the query works fine for me until I add an aggregated measure in the view.

SELECT rs.Field1,rs.Field2,rs.measure 
FROM (
    SELECT Field1,Field2, sum(cast(measure as INT)) over(partition by section) as agg_measure, ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (Partition BY Section
            ORDER BY agg_measure DESC ) AS Rank
    FROM table
    ) rs WHERE Rank <= 10

Can you please help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Q) Finding TOP X records from each group(Oracle)

```
SQL> select * from emp e 
  2  where e.empno in (select d.empno from emp d 
  3  where d.deptno=e.deptno and rownum<3)
  4  order by deptno
  5  ;

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
```

---

```
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
  7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
  7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
```

6 rows selected.

---

Comment: The question was about SQL Server, not Oracle.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to produce output grouped by section, displaying only the top *n* records from each section something like this:

```
SECTION     SUBSECTION

deer        American Elk/Wapiti
deer        Chinese Water Deer
dog         Cocker Spaniel
dog         German Shephard
horse       Appaloosa
horse       Morgan
```

...then the following should work pretty generically with all SQL databases.  If you want the top 10, just change the 2 to a 10 toward the end of the query.

```
select
    x1.section
    , x1.subsection
from example x1
where
    (
    select count(*)
    from example x2
    where x2.section = x1.section
    and x2.subsection <= x1.subsection
    ) <= 2
order by section, subsection;
```

To set up:

```
create table example ( id int, section varchar(25), subsection varchar(25) );

insert into example select 0, 'dog', 'Labrador Retriever';
insert into example select 1, 'deer', 'Whitetail';
insert into example select 2, 'horse', 'Morgan';
insert into example select 3, 'horse', 'Tarpan';
insert into example select 4, 'deer', 'Row';
insert into example select 5, 'horse', 'Appaloosa';
insert into example select 6, 'dog', 'German Shephard';
insert into example select 7, 'horse', 'Thoroughbred';
insert into example select 8, 'dog', 'Mutt';
insert into example select 9, 'horse', 'Welara Pony';
insert into example select 10, 'dog', 'Cocker Spaniel';
insert into example select 11, 'deer', 'American Elk/Wapiti';
insert into example select 12, 'horse', 'Shetland Pony';
insert into example select 13, 'deer', 'Chinese Water Deer';
insert into example select 14, 'deer', 'Fallow';
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I want just the first record for each section. It eliminates all section groups that have more than 1 record. I tried by replacing <=2 with <=1

Comment: @nils There are only three section values: deer, dog and horse. If you change the query to <= 1, you get one subsection for each section: American Elk/Wapiti for deer, Cocker Spaniel for dog and Appaloosa for horse. These are also the first values in each section alphabetically. The query is *meant* to eliminate all of the other values.

Comment: But when I try to run your query, it eliminates everything because the count is >=1 for everything. It doesn't preserve the 1st subsection for each section. Can you try to run your query for <=1 and let me know if you get the first subsection for each section?

Comment: @nils Hi, I did recreate this little test database from the scripts and ran the query using <= 1, and it returned the first subsection value from each section. What database server are you using? There's always a chance it's related to your database of choice. I just ran this in MySQL because it was handy and it behaved as expected. I'm pretty sure when I did it the first time (I wanted to make sure what I posted actually worked without debuggin), I'm pretty sure I did it using either Sybase SQL Anywhere or MS SQL Server.

Comment: it worked perfectly for me in mysql. I changed a query little bit not sure why did he used <= for varchar field in subsection.. i changed it to and x2.subsection = x1.subsection

Answer (score 5):

While the question was about SQL Server 2005, most people have moved on and if they do find this question, what could be the preferred answer in other situations is one [using `CROSS APPLY` as illustrated in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 10 u.*
  FROM u
  WHERE u.t_id = t.t_id
  ORDER BY u.something DESC
) u
```

This query involves 2 tables. The OP's query only involves 1 table, in case of which a window function based solution might be more efficient.

Comment: This was good stuff and appreciate the sql support and also used this link to get me going too.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/   Thanks.  Doug Lubey of Lousiana.

Answer (score 4):

Might the [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) operator work for you? Have one SELECT for each section, then UNION them together. Guess it would only work for a fixed number of sections though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach. 
This query returns 10 most populated cities for each country.

```
   SELECT city, country, population
   FROM
   (SELECT city, country, population, 
   @country_rank := IF(@current_country = country, @country_rank + 1, 1) AS country_rank,
   @current_country := country 
   FROM cities
   ORDER BY country, population DESC
   ) ranked
   WHERE country_rank <= 10;
```

Comment: This solution does not pass a test case when we have a table with a record of one country with 9 same population for example it returns null instead of returning all 9 available records in order. Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I know the OP has only 3 groups but this is a known general problem for many developers and there's no really good solution in SQL. So let me show you another way.*

---

#### IN THEORY:

You can write it as one query. That is, *formally one query,* but it contans either subqueries or a self-JOIN which makes it in fact multiple operations under the hood. So you might as well just select each group individually.

---

#### IN PRACTICE:

If you want a performant solution, you need to work a bit more. Let's say you have 100 employees, you have 26 buildings from A to Z, people move around them (enter/leave), and you need the last 5 events for every building.

```
EVENT_ID   EVENT_TIME            EMPOYEE_ID   EVENT_CODE   BUILDING                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------                                
883691     2023-03-29 11:00:00   92           enter        A                                           
883690     2023-03-29 11:00:21   78           enter        C                                           
883689     2023-03-29 11:00:25   58           enter        A                                           
883688     2023-03-29 11:02:10   22           leave        H                                           
883687     2023-03-29 11:31:42   73           leave        P                                           
...
...
```

You want to avoid 26 queries.

Here's what you can do:

1. Write a query with a simple ORDER BY EVENT_ID DESC (or EVENT_TIME DESC), to get the last N events for all buildings.
2. Set N (the limit) to a reasonable estimate that will have data for most buildings, you don't need to have *all of them* but the more the better. Let's say LIMIT 5000.
3. Process the result set on the application side, to see which buildings don't have the top 10 in it.
4. For those buildings, run separate queries to get their top 10.

For theorists, this is an anti-pattern. But the first query will have almost the same performance as one of the single-building ones, and probably brings you most of what you need; a few buildings will be missing, depending on how the employees normally move. Then, you may need 5 more queries for those buildings, and some merging on the application level.

**In short: get a result that's almost complete, then make it complete.**

So if you need performance, this is one way.
If you need clarity of the business logic, well, choose any other answer. This one is scary. But when you go for speed, you often need scary techniques.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight refinement (syntax only, swapping out a CASE statement for a GREATEST function) to Vadim Loboda's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27658678/352349).

```
DECLARE @N INT = 3; --the top "N" items to retrieve
WITH items(dt, category) AS
(
          SELECT '2000-01-01', 'group1' 
    UNION SELECT '2000-01-02', 'group1' 
    UNION SELECT '2000-01-03', 'group1' 
    UNION SELECT '2000-01-04', 'group1' 
    UNION SELECT '2000-01-05', 'group1' 
    UNION SELECT '1999-01-01', 'group2' 
    UNION SELECT '1999-01-02', 'group2' 
    UNION SELECT '1999-01-03', 'group2'
    UNION SELECT '1999-01-04', 'group2'
    UNION SELECT '2000-01-01', 'group3' 
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    category, 
    dt
FROM items
ORDER BY GREATEST(0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY dt ASC) - @N)
```

ROW_NUMBER is applied to each (partitioned by whatever we are grouping by), then subtract N from it so that it acquires a negative value for the first items, then the GREATEST function will instead return zero. All the rows with zero will then "tie" and TOP WITH TIES will give you just those rows.