# Efficiently select top row for each category in the set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I need to select a top row for each category from a known set (somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category)). The problem is, how to make this query efficient on the large number of rows.

For example, let's create a table that stores temperature recording in several places.

```
CREATE TABLE #t (
    placeId int,
    ts datetime,
    temp int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ts, placeId)
)

-- insert some sample data

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @n int, @ts datetime
SELECT @n = 1000, @ts = '2000-01-01'

WHILE (@n>0) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #t VALUES (@n % 10, @ts, @n % 37)
    IF (@n % 10 = 0) SET @ts = DATEADD(hour, 1, @ts)
    SET @n = @n - 1
END
```

Now I need to get the latest recording for each of the places 1, 2, 3.

This way is efficient, but doesn't scale well (and looks dirty).

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 1
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 2
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 3
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t3
```

The following looks better but works much less efficiently (30% vs 70% according to the optimizer).

```
SELECT placeId, ts, temp FROM (
    SELECT placeId, ts, temp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY placeId ORDER BY ts DESC) rownum
    FROM #t
    WHERE placeId IN (1, 2, 3)
) t
WHERE rownum = 1
```

The problem is, during the latter query execution plan a clustered index scan is performed on #t and 300 rows are retrieved, sorted, numbered, and then filtered, leaving only 3 rows. For the former query three times one row is fetched.

Is there a way to perform the query efficiently without lots of unions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded 100,000 rows (which still wasn't enough to slow things down), tried the old-fashioned way:

```
select t.*
 from #t t
  inner join (select placeId, max(ts) ts
               from #t
               where placeId in (1,2,3)
               group by placeId) xx
   on xx.placeId = t.placeId
    and xx.ts = t.ts
```

and got much the same results.

I then reversed the order of the columns in the index, to

```
CREATE TABLE #t ( 
    placeId int, 
    ts datetime, 
    temp int, 
    PRIMARY KEY (placeId, ts) 
)
```

and, in all the queries, got fewer page reads and index *seeks* instead of scans.

If optimization is your goal and you can modify indexes, I'd revised the primary key, or perhaps add a covering index.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the "old-fashioned way". It works better on my actual data structures too.

Answer (score 2):

don't just look at the execution plan also look at `statistics io` and `statistics time`

```
set statistics io on
go
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 1
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 2
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 3
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t3

SELECT placeId,  temp FROM (
    SELECT placeId, ts, temp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY placeId ORDER BY ts DESC) rownum
    FROM #t
    WHERE placeId IN (1, 2, 3)
) t
WHERE rownum = 1

set statistics io off
go
```

Table '#t000000000B99'. Scan count 3, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#t000000000B99'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

```
set statistics time on
go
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 1
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 2
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 3
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t3

SELECT placeId,  temp FROM (
    SELECT placeId, ts, temp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY placeId ORDER BY ts DESC) rownum
    FROM #t
    WHERE placeId IN (1, 2, 3)
) t
WHERE rownum = 1

set statistics time on
go
```

To me there is no real difference between the 2 methods, load up more data and compare again

ALso when you add an order by to both queries it drops to 40% vs 60%

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 1
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 2
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 placeId, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = 3
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) t3
ORDER BY placeId

SELECT placeId,  temp FROM (
    SELECT placeId,  temp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY placeId ORDER BY ts DESC) rownum
    FROM #t
    WHERE placeId IN (1, 2, 3)
) t
WHERE rownum = 1
ORDER BY placeId
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, another option using CROSS APPLY.
On my configuration, it performs better than all previously mentioned ones.

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) t (placeId)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 ts, temp
    FROM #t 
    WHERE placeId = t.placeId
    ORDER BY ts DESC
) tt
```

I'd guess, VALUES could be chaged to a temp table or a table variable without much difference.