# Select Top row from each group

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `DynamicText` with the following fields: `DynamicID`, `Content`, `Timestamp`, and `DynamicTextEnum`.

I'm trying to do design a query that would select the most recent record based on `Timestamp` from each of the groups that are grouped by `DynamicTextEnum`.

For example:

```
Enum    Timestamp
-----------------
1       1/10/2012
1       2/10/2012
2       1/10/2012
3       3/10/2012
2       3/10/2012
3       4/10/2012
```

So the results would look like this:

```
Enum    Timestamp
-----------------
1       2/10/2012
2       3/10/2012
3       4/10/2012
```

My current simply `SELECTS TOP 1` them based on Enum and orders them in DESC order based on
`Timestamp` but it doesn't work when I need all Enums. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DynamicTextEnum ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS rn
   FROM DynamicText
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question and answer:

[Efficiently select top row for each category in the set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974854/efficiently-select-top-row-for-each-category-in-the-set?rq=1)

You can do a sub-query to get the enum/timestamp pair, and join that with your full row.  That assumes you don't have duplicate timestamps for any given enum.