# How do i get top n records of each category

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, t-sql, plsql

I am here to get records based on categories.

My table **foo** has fields **[id, name, class]**. my records can be like:

```
1, ram, 10
2, hari, 9
3, sita, 10
4, gita, 9
5, rita, 5
6, tina, 7
8, nita, 8
9, bita, 5
10,seta, 7
```

...and more...

Now i would like to get result with each record from different class.. i.e something like

```
1, ram, 10
2, hari, 9
5, rita, 5
6, tina, 7
8, nita, 8
```

i.e just top **1** records as per class

Answer (score 6):

For SQL Server 2005+ and Oracle 9i+, use analytic functions:

```
WITH summary AS (
  SELECT f.id,
         f.name,
         f.class,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.class
                                ORDER BY f.name) AS rank
    FROM FOO f)
SELECT s.id,
       s.name,
       s.class
  FROM summary s
 WHERE s.rank = 1
```

This also uses a Common Table Expression (CTE), known as Subquery Factoring in Oracle...

MySQL doesn't have analytic function support, so you have to use:

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.name,
       x.class
  FROM (SELECT f.id,
               f.name,
               f.class,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @class = f.class THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := 1
               END AS rank,
               @class := f.class
          FROM FOO f
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @class := '') r
      ORDER BY f.class, f.name) x
 WHERE x.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be the easiest way, which doesn't involve any database-specific options:

```
select * 
  from foo 
 where id in (select min(id) 
                from foo 
               group by class);
```

upd: yeah, of course this would work only if you need only one record from each class.

upd2: just for fun come up with a query thta shows you TOP N and doesn't involve analytics. looks kinda messy, but seems to work :)

```
select newfoo.id, newfoo.name, newfoo.class
  from (select class, max(r) top, min(r) bottom
          from (select f.*, rownum r
                  from (select id, name, class from foo order by class, id asc) f)
         group by class) minmax,
       (select id, name, class, r
          from (select f.*, rownum r
                  from (select id, name, class from foo order by class, id asc) f)) newfoo
 where newfoo.class = minmax.class
   and newfoo.r between minmax.bottom and
       least(minmax.bottom + (TOP_N-1), minmax.top);
```

where `TOP_N` is amount of records you need to get.

Comment: hmm... quite interesting and good one... for single record. can it be modified for top n records

Answer (score 3):

I tested in sql 2008 this and works for me, hope that helps you in some way.

```
DECLARE @Class TABLE
(
    id INT
    ,Name NVARCHAR(120)
    ,Class INT

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO @Class values (1, 'ram', 10)
INSERT INTO @Class values (2, 'hari', 9)
INSERT INTO @Class values (3, 'sita', 10)
INSERT INTO @Class values (4, 'gita', 9)
INSERT INTO @Class values (5, 'rita', 5)
INSERT INTO @Class values (6, 'tina', 7)
INSERT INTO @Class values (8, 'nita', 8)
INSERT INTO @Class values (9, 'bita', 5)
INSERT INTO @Class values (10, 'seta', 7)

SELECT A.id, A.Name, A.Class
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY ID) as Num, ID, Name, Class
    FROM @Class
) A
WHERE A.Num = 1
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: No, it's from sql 2005 +. You need it for SQL 2000?

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server or Oracle (or any other engine implementing that part of the standard, including e.g. PostgreSQL among the free ones), the "window functions" in an `OVER` clause (e.g., see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) for MS's docs about them) make it easy; e.g., in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category), see @Darrel's answer (he's selecting the top 10 per category, you only want the top 1, the changes should be obvious;-).

In MySql, or other engine not complying with the standard regarding the `OVER` clause, you could use @Bill's answer (good for MySql, not for others) or @Matt's (may need slight adaptation since he's answering for SQL Server and so using `SELECT TOP 10 ...` -- in MySql that would be `SELECT ... LIMIT 10`!-).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
    DECLARE @foo TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(20),Class INT)
INSERT INTO @foo
SELECT 1,'ram', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'hari', 9 UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 'sita', 10  UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'gita', 9  UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'rita', 5  UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'tina', 7  UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'nita', 8  UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'bita', 5  UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'seta', 7

SELECT DISTINCT X.*
FROM @foo f
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @foo WHERE Class = f.Class) AS X
```