# Can't write query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am writing SQL Server database, where I have a relation UserTypedText(userId, date, textId, speed). (which user when types which text in which speed) Where (userId, date) is key. So I want to query from this table last 10 (sorted by date decreasing order) rows for each user. If user has not typed 10 texts, then get all information about his types. Can you please help me with this query? It is very important to do all this via single query, to not UNION results of results.

Comment: Similar old question: is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From SQL 2005 and later, you can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) with PARTITION BY to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNo, *
FROM UserTypedText
) x
WHERE x.RowNo <= 10
```

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2005/2008, we can use CTEs and ROW_NUMBER() to get what we want... this is untested, but should work:

```
;WITH numbered AS (
    SELECT userId, date, textId, speed, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY date DESC) AS user_row_number
        FROM UserTypedText
)
SELECT userId, date, textId, speed 
    FROM numbered 
    WHERE user_row_number <= 10 
    ORDER BY userId, date
```

This returns the top 10 for every user in a single result set, ordered by user and date.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a stored procedure that would take the user Id of the user you are interested in, and for each user:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM UserTypedText
WHERE userId = @userId
ORDER BY date
```

Where `@userId` is the passed in parameter.

Comment: What means "for each user"? I want to do this by single query, to get all data on one table.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan - And if you have 10,000 users?

Comment: I want to sort all users by order of thery Average speed of last 10 races.
I will be glad If I would have 10000 users :)

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan - I suggest you edit your question and change it to this last requirement. You should be able to get the average of the last 10 races and order by it in one query.

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestion.
But there is already few question, I don't wan't them to become incorrect after my change. And also I've already get answer of what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a join on your user table:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Users AS U INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 10 *
                       FROM UserTypedText as T
                       Where T.userID = U.userID
                       Order By date DESC)
```