# Return top 10 per year

Tags: sql, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to return the top 10 products per year, how can I do this with my following query?

```
SELECT 
   DP.ProductID
   , DP.Name
   , Year(FS.OrderDate) as TheYear
   , FS.OrderQty
   , FS.OrderAmount
FROM dbo.DimProduct AS DP
LEFT JOIN dbo.FactSales as FS on FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID
```

Comment: Top 10 -- Based on what criteria?

Comment: See previous effort for similar task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category

Comment: Based on amount of products sold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be easy if your RDBMS supports `Window Functions`

```
SELECT  ProductID,
        Name,
        TheYear,
        OrderQty,
        OrderAmount
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  DP.ProductID
                    ,DP.Name
                    ,Year(FS.OrderDate) as TheYear
                    ,FS.OrderQty
                    ,FS.OrderAmount,
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER() (PARTITION BY Year(FS.OrderDate) 
                                        ORDER BY FS.OrderQty DESC) rn
            FROM    dbo.DimProduct AS DP
                    LEFT JOIN dbo.FactSales as FS 
                        on FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID
        ) s
WHERE   rn <= 10
ORDER   BY TheYear
```

- [TSQL Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

The current query will give you `10` products for every `TheYear` based on `FS.OrderQty` since you have not mentioned the criteria on how the records will be sorted out.

The `ROW_NUMBER()` (*a RANKING function*) will generate a sequence of number for each group, in this case `Year(FS.OrderDate)`, that is sorted out based on `FS.OrderQty`. The records will then be filtered out based on the value of the generated sequence.

---

However, if `ROW_NUMBER()` will not generate `TIE` on the records having the same `FS.OrderQty`. If you want it to be handled, use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: I assume that `TOP 10` product of each year means acording to `OrderQty*OrderAmount`.

Comment: Probably looking for ORDER BY FS.OrderQty or FS.OrderAmount for top 10 products per year.  Think sales reporting.

Comment: @TimSchmelter good point. not sure since the OP did not mentioned about any criteria.

Comment: This is the way to go.  However you may have duplicate amounts in which case you may want to use Rank() instead of Row_Number().  Row_Number will give you 10 rows no matter what.  Rank may give more than 10 rows if you have a tie in your quantity.  For instance, let's say in a race 3 people tie for second place and you say you want the top 2.  Using Row_Number you would get the #1 finisher and just one of the #2 finishers (1, random 2).  Using Rank you would get the #1 finisher and all three #2 finishers ( 1, 2, 2, 2)

Comment: @PapaBurgundy thank you for your concern, but in that case, I rather use `DENSE_RANK()` than `RANK()`.

Comment: @JW웃 well it depends on what you're trying to achieve.  Let's say that in my example you want the top 3 finishers.  Rank would give you 1 and all of the 2s, which is what I want.  There would be no 3rd or 4th place finisher.  The next one would be 5th.  If I were to use Dense_Rank it would return the 4th and 5th place people which is not what I would want.  So it just depends on what you're after.  Each one has its own purpose.

Comment: @PapaBurgundy I'm not against you or whatsoever. `:)` My answer is based on what the OP wants. Yes, each of each ranking function has its own purpose.

Comment: @JW웃 No worries.  I'm trying to help the OP as well.  He doesn't specify his exact definition of top 10.  Row_Number(), Rank(), and Dense_Rank() are all options for him.  He'll need to make that decision based on his application.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the function `row_number()` to get the top 10.  This assumes that `OrderQty` defines the top 10:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT DP.ProductID, DP.Name, Year(FS.OrderDate) as TheYear, FS.OrderQty, FS.OrderAmount,
             row_number() over (partition by Year(FS.OrderDate)
                                order by fs.OrderAmount desc
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.DimProduct DP LEFT JOIN
           dbo.FactSales FS
           on FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID
    ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

The function `row_number()` enumerates rows, starting with 1.  It starts over within each group, as defined by the `partition by` clause (in your case, the year).  The ordering of the numbers is based on the `order by` clause (in your case, `fs.OrderAmount desc`).  So, the ten best products in each year will have the numbers 1-10 and the `where` clause just chooses them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   DP.ProductID
   , DP.Name
   , Year(FS.OrderDate) as TheYear
   , FS.OrderQty
   , FS.OrderAmount 
   , (FS.OrderQty * FS.OrderAmount) AS FS.Total
FROM dbo.DimProduct AS DP
LEFT JOIN dbo.FactSales as FS on FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID
GROUP BY TheYear, DP.ProductID, FS.Total
ORDER BY FS.Total DESC
WHERE seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: I have changed the code to display top ten products each year.

Comment: Where did "seqnum" come from?  Is this T-SQL (per the tagging of the question) or another SQL variant keyword?