# How to pull top 3 per group in access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm attempting to pull the top three performers in a group. I'm not sure how to do this in Access, what I need is for each group to pull the top three.

http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html

I've tried these subqueries however they give me an error message. Is there a better way to do this?

It's for keyword performance.

Table fields are

```
Keyword | Campaign | Ad Group |  Clicks | Impressions
```

I want the top 3 for clicks for each ad group. I want top 3 impressions too but once I know how to do clicks I'll be able to modify it as needed. 
I'm trying to get like

```
Ad Group 1 - First Top
Ad Group 1 - Second Top
Ad Group 1 - Third Top
Ad Group 2 - First Top
Ad Group 2 - Second Top
Ad Group 2 - Third Top
etc

SELECT KeywordReport.ID, KeywordReport.Campaign, KeywordReport.[Ad group], KeywordReport.Keyword, KeywordReport.Clicks, KeywordReport.Impressions, KeywordReport.[Avg CPC], KeywordReport.[Search Impr share], KeywordReport.Cost
FROM KeywordReport
WHERE (((KeywordReport.ID) In (SELECT TOP 3 ID 
FROM KeywordReport AS Dupe
WHERE Dupe.ID = KeywordReport.ID
ORDER BY Dupe.Clicks DESC)))
ORDER BY KeywordReport.[Ad group];
```

It is returning all entries not the top 3.

Comment: What is the error message you get with that SQL?

Comment: @HansUp I don't get an error message it just shows me all of the records in the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [select top 10 records for each category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category)

Answer (score 0):

I think you were close:

```
WHERE (((KeywordReport.ID) In (SELECT TOP 3 ID 
FROM KeywordReport AS Dupe
WHERE Dupe.[Ad Group] = KeywordReport.[Ad Group]   <-- change this line
ORDER BY Dupe.Clicks DESC)))
```

Comment: This causes Access to freeze. Maybe it's too large of a database?

Comment: Very likely.  It's essentially doing a subquery for each record.  Adding an index on `AdGroup` may help.

Comment: Actually, it hasn't frozen Access the query is running just very very slowly. I think I'm going to try to do this in PHP and mySQL. I think that would be better. Then I can just do a for Each loop. I don't know. I'm hoping this works but if it takes a full day to run each time it won't.

Comment: If there's not much more than 3 items in each group that may work.  The drawback is you have to fetch _all_ of the data when you only need the first 3 rows for each group.

Comment: There are quite a few for each group. I'm not sure how to limit the data very well.

Comment: No, don't fetch all the data. If you have your groups indexed in a separate table, you can fetch the top 3 where group = 'x'. Then wrap that in a loop. If you don't have that separate table, try selecting distinct on the group field and using that.