# MySQL : select a few rows for each value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sample

[Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1131/1/0)

I have a simple table looking like this :

```
USER_NAME   STATUS
------------------
Paul        1
John        4
Brad        1
Simon       1
Jack        4
```

I have 10 different status and around 2000 rows (users).

I want to export a small sample of rows from each status from my production database. Then I will import them in my dev database to run tests

I want a query that select a few (let's say 3) rows for each value of the `status` field

- 3 users with status 1
- 3 users with status 2
- 3 users with status 3
- ...

How could I achieve that ? Do i have to do a loop on STATUS and use LIMIT ?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT** : edited for clarity

Comment: This will do what you want... SELECT * FROM users;

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very clear : I don't care which 3, I will have like 10 different status and I want to export a sample of each status from my production database. Then I will import them in my dev database to run tests

Answer (score 2):

For this size of data, it might be easiest to use `union all`:

```
(select t.* from table t where status = 1 order by rand() limit 3)
union all
(select t.* from table t where status = 2 order by rand() limit 3)
union all
. . .
union all
(select t.* from table t where status = 10 order by rand() limit 3)
```

There are other methods that would perform better.  But this should be quite reasonable on the volume of data you have.

Comment: I like your answer but I don't really care about performances. I'm more interested in a simple query I can store somewhere and reuse and adapt to other cases. If somedaw I have a similar case but with more status this method wouldn't be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query for a single status, you can extend it by changing the number though...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name JOIN users ON ( users.Status = status.Id ) WHERE status.Id = 1 GROUP BY status LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

SELECT users  FROM  table WHERE status=max(status) ORDER status LIMIT BY 3

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/177212/2430274):

```
SELECT a.user_name, a.status
FROM table AS a
LEFT JOIN table AS b
    ON a.status = b.status
    AND a.created_at <= b.created_at
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING count(*) <= 3
ORDER BY a.status
```

Tested on MySQL 5.5