# How to retrieve max salary of employee from each department

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the table Employee:

```
Department number      Employee_id      Salary
   1                       123           2000
   1                       234           3266
   1                       657           3265
   2                       546           2050
   2                       657           3000
   2                       121           6000
   3                       131           6500
   3                       141           5000
   3                       151           1050
```

Now I want to retrieve the employee_id having highest salary from each department. How to write the query for this?

Comment: Well. .. This was asked in my interview.  I don't know the logic to try.

Comment: Before you go to that schools site, please see http://w3fools.com.

Comment: This is a variation on the classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem; see answers in this question: [select top 10 records for each category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category).  Stuff like this gets too many duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to approach these queries is using `row_number()`:

```
select department_number, employee_id, salary
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want to get multiple rows for a department when there are ties, then use `dense_rank()` or `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Dept_Num,EmpID,Salary
from Employee
WHERE Salary IN (Select MAX(Salary) from Employee Group By Dept_Num)
```

Comment: @Karthik . . . This does not work in all cases.  Consider if the data had the value "1, xxx, 151".

Answer (score -3):

Can you use the **max** statement:

```
Select departament_number,employee_id,salary
from employee
where salary in (select MAX(salary) from employee group by departament_number)
```

Comment: Including the employee_id in the group by would result in a result for each employee rather than a single record for the department.