# How to write SQL query to extract log data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is a master table containing master data.

One column contains unique IDs. A second is a log table.

For one unique ID (master table ID) nearly 3 to 4 records are in the log table.

I want to fetch master data and its log table data (top record for unique id in descending order).

Eg.

**Master table**

```
id      guid       desc      depid 
----------------------------- 
1       fg1          hii           1
2       h6           hoo          2
```

**Log table**

```
id      guid   fromqueue     toqueue   status
-----------------------------------------------
1       fg1          1                        2                1
2       fg1          2                        3                2
3       h6           1                        4                2
4       h6           4                        5                3
```

For example, here I want to fetch data like below

```
id     guid       desc      depid    status  
-----------------------------------------------
1      fg1          hii              1           2   
2      h6           hoo              2           3
```

What is the query for getting this result?

Comment: Where is the statement that isn't working?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select top 10 records for each category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select m.*, l.status
from master m join
     log l
     on m.guid = l.guid
where not exists (select 1
                  from log l2
                  where l2.guid = l.guid and
                        l2.id > l.id
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `log(guid, id)`.  This transforms the statement to:  "Get me all records from the `log` table that have the same `guid` and no higher `id`."  That is equivalent to getting the last record, assuming the `id` column is an identity column.

Comment: @nixen09 . . . That surprises me.  The code looks like it should be returning the status only from the log record with the highest id for each `guid`.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @ Gordon Sorry for the wrong statement..its working perfectly..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT   master.id AS id, master.guid AS guid, desc, depid, MAX(status) AS status
FROM     master
JOIN     log ON master.id = log.id
GROUP BY master.id, master.guid, desc
```

Comment: hi, its not working . I tried . Its giving different status id. Not according to my above requirements .