# Group by and show records by criteria MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have the following table :

```
     | PID | FullName | Position | Salary | Status    | DateHired
     | 11  | Dave     | Clerk    | 100    | Extended  | 2014-01-30
     | 11  | Dave     | Clerk    | 100    | Hired     | 2014-01-02
     | 22  | Chris    | Guard    | 80     | Extended  | 2014-01-30
     | 22  | Chris    | DJ       | 100    | Hired     | 2014-01-02
     | 33  | Dud      | Clerk    | 200    | Terminated| 2014-01-30
     | 33  | Dud      | Clerk    | 200    | Hired     | 2014-01-03
     | 44  | Trish    | Clerk    | 200    | Hired     | 2014-01-25
```

I need to be able to output each record grouped by PID, and their latest status. If their latest status is terminated, it should be ignored.
The output should be like this:

```
     | PID | FullName | Position | Salary | Status    | DateHired
     | 11  | Dave     | Clerk    | 100    | Extended  | 2014-01-30
     | 22  | Chris    | Guard    | 80     | Extended  | 2014-01-30
     | 44  | Trish    | Clerk    | 200    | Hired     | 2014-01-25
```

Dud has been terminated, so he isn't shown on the table.

Is there a query for this? or should I just link the table to .net, and loop from there?

What I did that also worked is the ff:

1. I queried the entire table (with select ) into a datatable ordered by PID then DateHired (asc)
2. looped for each record in the datatable
3. and copied the last record detected win the loop for that PID into another datatable as long as the Status != "Terminated"

*EDIT* Corrected the sample table given

*EDIT* Included the solution I've tried.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select top 10 records for each category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category)

Comment: In my defense, I feel that that question is unclear without sample tables to work with. 
I gave an example table, and a result of what I wanted from it.

Comment: You should at least have shown what you attempted to get _any_ results.  It's good that you gave starting data/expected results, and it was nicely formatted.  I agree that sometimes being able to _find_ related questions/answers can be difficult - that's why we're here, to point you in the right direction(s).

Comment: I included the solution I've tried that worked. Please don't close this question, as I feel other users like me can learn from it.
I also often look back at the questions that I've asked as reference for other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dud has been terminated, but the hire date is afterwards.  So, the data you provide and the logic are not consistent.  To get the most recent status and to remove those that are terminated, use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by pid order by datehired desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and status <> 'Terminated';
```

`row_number()` assigns a sequential value starting with `1` to a set of rows.  The set of rows is defined by the `partition by` clause, so in this example, all rows with the same `pid` are in the same set.  The enumeration is then based on the `order by` clause, so in this case, the row with the largest value of `datehired` in the set gets a value of `1`.  The `where` clause chooses where the value is `1`, so that is the largest `datehired` for each `pid`.

Comment: Oh my I'm sorry! the date is supposed to be 2014-01-30! I'll fix it