# SQL query MAX functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch data for a perticular product on basis of last user & respective last used time.Example

```
Host   Product   LastUserName   LastUsedTime
1      X1        ABC            6/13/2014
1      X1        ABC            6/14/2014
1      X1        ABC            6/15/2014
1      X1        XYZ            6/14/2014
1      X1        XYZ            6/15/2014
1      X1        XYZ            6/16/2014
```

I have tried MAX function and find data as

```
Host   Product   LastUserName   LastUsedTime
1      X1        ABC            6/15/2014
1      X1        XYZ            6/16/2014
```

But unable to get desired output which is

```
Host   Product   LastUserName   LastUsedTime
1      X1        XYZ            6/16/2014
```

SQL:

```
select a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0, c.LastUserName0,
       MAX(c.LastUsedTime0) as [Last Used Time] 
from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c 
where a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID 
    and a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID 
group by a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0, c.LastUserName0 
order by b.DisplayName0
```

Thanks for Help !!

Comment: Any particular RDBMS? MySQL? Oracle? ...?

Comment: Please show your query.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY ... DESC` with `LIMIT 1` or `TOP 1` ... instead

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : SQL

Comment: @Barmar : select a.Netbios_Name0,b.DisplayName0,c.LastUserName0,MAX(c.LastUsedTime0) as [Last Used Time]
from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c
where a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID and
a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID
group by a.Netbios_Name0,b.DisplayName0,c.LastUserName0
order by b.DisplayName0

Comment: @zerkms: DESC LIMIT 1 not working.
even DESC is not changing the output

Comment: Where are `Host` and `Product` in your query?

Comment: Host referes to Netbios_Name0 and product refers to b.DisplayName0

Comment: Why do you make things confusing by changing the names?

Comment: See in example i have shown in 2nd table ..
i am getting a single product which has 2 LastUserName on basis of LastUsedTime respectively.
and i Want further filteration which i have shown in table 3
single product, and LastUserName based on Max LastUsedTime.

Comment: What would be the expected result when two or more users last used the same product on the same day? (e.g. if the record for 16-May-2014 was not in the sample data). Do you include time in the sequence of events?

Comment: possible duplicate of [select top 10 records for each category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category)

Comment: @KevinHogg: Yes possibility is there but that be the least case.
but still did not get desired output.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: TOP clause would not work in my case.
as i want every product with single user with respective MAXDate

Comment: @moronrats - Check the first answer, please, which doesn't use the `TOP` clause.  This is a classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem; your filtering of `Terminated` users just has to be after getting the greatest row.

Answer (score 1):

For MSSQL :

```
select a.host, a.Product, a.LastUserName, a.LastUsedTime
from tablex a join 
(
select Host, Product, max(LastUsedTime) as LastUsedTime
    from tablex
    group by Host, Product 
) b on a.host = b.host and a.Product = b.Product and a.LastUsedTime = b.LastUsedTime
```

Comment: example of sample query
select a.Netbios_Name0,b.DisplayName0,c.LastUserName0,MAX(c.LastUsedTime0) as [Last Used Time]
from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c
where a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID and
a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID
group by a.Netbios_Name0,b.DisplayName0,c.LastUserName0
order by b.DisplayName0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_name ORDER BY LastUsername DESC,  LastUsedTime DESC
```

Comment: LIMIT is for MySQL, not SQL-Server.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one row, don't use `GROUP BY`. Just order the results and use `TOP 1` to get the first row (`LIMIT 1` is for MySQL -- this is why you should always tell your RDBMS in questions).

```
select TOP 1 a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0, c.LastUserName0, c.LastUsedTime0
from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c 
where a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID 
    and a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID 
ORDER BY c.LastUsedTime0 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for help man !!
Its working fine and providing a single row based on LastUsedTime.
but as i have shown in example output should on basis of every product ,LastUserName,LastUsedTime respectively

Comment: That's not what your example shows. You said the desired output is just one row with the highest `LastUsedTime`.

Comment: You said the output with every product and user name was wrong.

Comment: desired output should be every product with LastUserName and respective LastUsedTime.

Comment: How is that different from what you showed in the question?

Comment: just see the differences in table 2 and table 3

Comment: I give up, you're too confusing. There is no table 2 and table 3 in the question.

Comment: This fiddle produces what you said is the desired output. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7d5c3/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT      TOP 1 a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0, c.LastUserName0,
            c.LastUsedTime0 as [Last Used Time] 
FROM        table1 a INNER JOIN
            table2 b ON a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID INNER JOIN
            table3 c ON a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID
WHERE       c.LastUsedTime0 = (SELECT TOP 1 LastUsedTime0 FROM table3 WHERE ResourceID = c.ResourceID)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the row with the last date per product you first need to get that last date, then `JOIN` back to the others values

```
WITH L AS (
  SELECT b.DisplayName0, MAX(c.LastUsedTime0) LastUsedTime0
  FROM   table2 b
         INNER JOIN table3 c ON b.ResourceID = c.ResourceID
  GROUP BY b.DisplayName0
)
SELECT a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0, c.LastUserName0
     , c.LastUsedTime0 as [Last Used Time] 
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID
       INNER JOIN table3 c ON a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID
       INNER JOIN L ON b.DisplayName0 = L.DisplayName0
                   AND c.LastUsedTime0 = L.LastUsedTime0
ORDER BY b.DisplayName0
```

if you need to separate also the host name you need to change the query to

```
WITH L AS (
  SELECT a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0, MAX(c.LastUsedTime0) LastUsedTime0
  FROM   table1 a
         INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID
         INNER JOIN table3 c ON a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID
  GROUP BY a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0
)
SELECT a.Netbios_Name0, b.DisplayName0, c.LastUserName0
     , c.LastUsedTime0 as [Last Used Time] 
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.ItemKey = b.ResourceID
       INNER JOIN table3 c ON a.ItemKey = c.ResourceID
       INNER JOIN L ON a.Netbios_Name0 = L.Netbios_Name0
                   AND b.DisplayName0 = L.DisplayName0
                   AND c.LastUsedTime0 = L.LastUsedTime0
ORDER BY b.DisplayName0
```

As a last advice please stop to write the `JOIN` definition in the `WHERE` clause, it's less readable and mix to different ideas

Comment: I have the same thought "To get the row with the last date per product you first need to get that last date"
but can you explain "WITH L" ?
I didn't get that.

Comment: No output received.
blank columns.

Comment: I have created schema. please check [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25683/1)
just check with your query for desired output, i have tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Product_Usage.*
   FROM Product_Usage
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Product, max(LastUsedTime) LastUSedTime
                      FROM Product_Usage
                     GROUP BY Product) LastUsed
                ON Product_Usage.Product = LastUsed.Product
               AND Product_Usage.LastUsedTime = LastUsed.LastUsedTime
```

Answer (score 0):

;with cte as
(
select  max(lastusedtime) over (PARTITION by product) as mdate
         ,host,product,lastusername ,lastusedtime 
         from test1
)
select distinct host,product,lastusername ,lastusedtime from cte
where lastusedtime=mdate[image]

Comment: If there are 2 products X1 and X2. this query giving output any of the product which has maxdate. but as per desired output both of the products should be present into the output with their respective lastusername and maxdate

Comment: Your desired output is one row with max date according to ur question.Am i right?

Comment: depends on products.
if 1 product then 1 output
if 2 product then 2 output

Comment: i ran the query on fiddle **with TEMP as ( Select MAX(c.LastUsedTime) OVER (PARTITION BY b.Product) as mdate,a.Host, b.Product,c.LastUserName,c.LastUsedTime From table1 a INNER JOIN table2 b ON table1.itemkey = table2.resourceid INNER JOIN table3 c ON table1.itemkey = table3.resourceid ) Select Distinct Host,Product,LastUserName,LastUsedTime from TEMP Where LastUserName = mdate** but its throwing error of multi-part identifier. 
[link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25683/1)