# Select from each group the last n rows orders by date in DB2

Tags: sql, database, select, db2

I'm using `DB2` database. I have a table that contains the following columns:

```
Group | Name | Date | Value
```

I want to select the 10 last values (ordered by date) for each Group. How can I do that in DB2 ? Many thanks.

UPDATE :

Here is what I did so far :

```
select Group, DATE
from MyTable
ORDER BY Group, DATE 
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

This sql command return the first 10 rows of the results and I want to get 10 last results for each Group.

Comment: your query with order by desc, `FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: change your `order by` clause to use descending `desc`

Comment: I think you didn't understand the problem. I don't want to get 10 last rows of all the records but the 10 last of each group. Even if I add `desc` it returns only the last 10 rows of the global result

Comment: You may want to read this; 
     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category

Comment: and also this [how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/). there is a piece there on how to get top N rows per group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with a simple `order by` clause; you need to use an OLAP function:

```
with ordered as (
  select group, 
         date, 
         row_number() over (partition by group order by date desc) as date_rank
    from mytable
)
select group, date 
  from ordered 
  where date_rank <= 10
```