# Selecting a record with max value on one of the joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have three related tables and need to select rows that show data from two tables based on a value (serial number) from the third. I am only interested in the max value of the serial number. I have tried multiple solutions suggested here on stackoverflow and I still cannot get my head around this.

A sample code for my tables with a straight forward SELECT for all values are available here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b8f7/4/0

My end goal is to obtain a table like this:

```
reference   groupname   serialnum
C:123       Group2      3
C:125       Group1      4
C:126       Group1      1
```

Ordering with LIMIT does not seem to work. 
Any ideas how this might be addressed?

**DDL + DML for Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE pm_process
    ([pm_guid] int, [Descr] varchar(4), [usr_newref] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO pm_process
    ([pm_guid], [Descr], [usr_newref])
VALUES
    (11111, 'aaaa', 'C:123'),
    (22222, 'bbbb', 'C:125'),
    (33333, 'cccc', 'C:126')
;


CREATE TABLE tps_group
    ([tps_title] varchar(6), [tps_guid] int)
;

INSERT INTO tps_group
    ([tps_title], [tps_guid])
VALUES
    ('Group1', 99999),
    ('Group2', 88888)
;


CREATE TABLE pm_process_assignment
    ([pm_group_guid] int, [pm_process_guid] int, [pm_serial_number] int)
;

INSERT INTO pm_process_assignment
    ([pm_group_guid], [pm_process_guid], [pm_serial_number])
VALUES
    (99999, 11111, 1),
    (99999, 11111, 2),
    (88888, 11111, 3),
    (88888, 22222, 1),
    (99999, 22222, 2),
    (88888, 22222, 3),
    (99999, 22222, 4),
    (99999, 33333, 1)
;
```

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Few humans understand those. Save the world and use LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: SQL Server/T-SQL doesn't use `limit` but rather `top`.

Comment: @jarlh: It's only a matter of perspective. you can look at the screen through a mirror of that helps :-)

Comment: @Pawzik: Linking to sql fiddle is excellent, It may save a lot of time and effort from whoever wants to answer your question. However, you should include the DDL and DML in your message as well, since sql fiddle suffers from a lot of downtime.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category?rq=1

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Noted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server, probably the easiest way to do this is using [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT p.usr_newref as reference,
       pag.tps_title as groupname,
       pag.pm_serial_number as serialnum
FROM pm_process p OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 pa.pm_serial_number, g.tps_title
      FROM pm_process_assignment pa JOIN
           tps_group g
           ON g.tps_guid = pa.pm_group_guid
      WHERE pa.pm_process_guid = p.pm_guid
      ORDER BY pm_serial_number DESC
     ) pag
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b8f7/23) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @Gordon: I've added the link to the relevant technet page. hope you don't mind...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to locate records having the maximum `serialnum` within each `reference` partition. Then, in an outer query, select only these records:

```
SELECT reference, groupname, serialnum
FROM (
SELECT
  pm_process.usr_newref as reference,
  pm_assignment_group.tps_title as groupname,
  process_assignments.pm_serial_number as serialnum,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pm_process.usr_newref 
                     ORDER BY process_assignments.pm_serial_number DESC) AS rn
FROM
  tps_group  pm_assignment_group 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN pm_process_assignment  process_assignments 
    ON (pm_assignment_group.tps_guid=process_assignments.pm_group_guid)
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN pm_process 
    ON (process_assignments.pm_process_guid=pm_process.pm_guid)
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b8f7/12)

Comment: This also gives me what I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `RANK` AND `CTE`. It will handle situation when multiple pm_serial_number has the same value.

```
WITH RankTable AS
(

    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY usr_newref 
        ORDER BY pm_serial_number DESC) AS R
    FROM pm_process
    LEFT JOIN pm_process_assignment 
        ON pm_process_assignment.pm_process_guid = pm_process.pm_guid
    LEFT JOIN tps_group 
        ON tps_group.tps_guid = pm_process_assignment.pm_group_guid
)
SELECT usr_newref, tps_title, pm_serial_number 
FROM RankTable 
WHERE RankTable.R = 1
```