# SQL, set limit for a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I have a problem with this SQL-Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM page p 
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to IN
(
  'Art-Rock-Band',
  'Echo-Pop-Preisträger',
  'Englische_Band',
  'Genesis_(Band)',
  'Grammy-Preisträger',
  'Peter_Gabriel',
  'Phil_Collins',
  'Popband',
  'Progressive-Rock-Band',
  'Rock_and_Roll_Hall_of_Fame'
)
```

It works and I get a very big result of every page where `p.page_id = c.cl_from`

Now I want to set a limit for every single category because the query takes too long.

I want just 5 results for '`Art-Rock-Band`', just 5 results for '`Echo-Pop-Preisträger`' etc...

Comment: This may be a duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category

Comment: I'm not familiar with mysql analytic functions, but if there is RANK like orace, you can use it to rank the columns in C table partitioned by the cl column and then take only those whos lower then 5

Comment: DO you want 'Art-Rock-Band' and 'Echo-Pop-Preisrager' in one query?

Comment: @sagi - no windowing functions in mysql

Comment: @sagi I think the purpose was to get the top 5 from each category, rather than only showing results whose sets number 5 or less.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is somewhat lengthy (unless someone else has a better idea) but you can use `UNION ALL` to display the top 5 results from a series of smaller queries following this pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Art-Rock-Band'
LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Echo-Pop-Preisträger'
LIMIT 5
...
```

You could also get fancy and replace the 5 with a variable so that you can control how many results you get from everything with a simple change:

```
DECLARE @num INT DEFAULT 5;

SELECT * FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Art-Rock-Band'
LIMIT @num
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Echo-Pop-Preisträger'
LIMIT @num
...
```

As an added value, I put in a second declaration (commented out, of course) of the same variable in the instance you might want to recall by percent rather than a set number.

I hope this helps point you in the right direction at least.

-C§

EDIT: For SQL Server, replace `LIMIT @num` with `TOP @num` before the `UNION ALL` in each query and replace the `DEFAULT` with `=`. You can also have a second line to declare the @num as a string and use the `PERCENT` keyword, but only in SQL Server as neither MySQL nor Oracle supports it.

For Oracle, you can replace it similarly with an addition to the `WHERE` clause: `AND ROWNUM <= @num`. You also want to update the `DECLARE` statement to prepend a colon to the equals so `=` becomes `:=`.

This should account for the primary differences from the above MySQL examples for any coming behind that have a similar question in the other two formats. More explanation can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp.

Comment: Did you noticed that the question is tagged with `MySQL`? Cause there is no `TOP` in `MySQL`.

Comment: But isn't it in the UNION ALL case, that i just can search for two categorylinks not for this all in my question? or can i put the other categorys under last where clausle where you put the three points in?

Comment: UNION ALL can give duplicate lines... not sure the user wants that.

Comment: @hogan duplicate lines when each query is searching a different category? Surely you do jest, sir.

Comment: @CSS I don't jest -- category could (and I expect does) have more than one entry per page.

Comment: @Hogan I guess we would have to ask the OP for a set of example data and whether he would care about multiple page_id values per category generating separate results. Either way, I don't think this would be likely to generate duplicate rows. At worst, he can add the `DISTINCT` keyword, and likely would need to for both of our responses, in order to filter it down.

Comment: @CSS - all of this is true... `DISTINCT` always leaves a bad taste in my mouth -- probably just a troubled childhood.

Comment: It returns that i have to use the right syntax in 'DECLARE INT @num = 5'

Comment: nethertheless it returns the error for this `DECLARE @num INT = 5;`.. sry :/

Comment: using SET it works but then he sad use the right syntax for `'@num * FROM page p LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from WHERE c.c' `

Comment: @Name I have updated to showcase MySQL for you and have correctly annotated that only SQL Server supports the `PERCENT` keyword. If this finally works for you, please mark it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think it does not work my query looks like this: `DECLARE @num INT = 5;

SELECT * FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Art-Rock-Band'
TOP @num
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to = 'Echo-Pop-Preisträger'
TOP @num
` nethertheless the same error with not right syntax for '`DECLARE @num INT = 5`'

Comment: @Name `DECLARE @num DEFAULT 5;` before the query, `LIMIT @num;` after the query. That is the final answer, as depicted in my final edit above. I think you understand to use `UNION ALL` between each pair of queries. I'm sorry it was confusing you before.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * 
FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to IN
(
  'Art-Rock-Band'
)
LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT  * 
FROM page p
LEFT JOIN categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
WHERE c.cl_to IN
(

  'Echo-Pop-Preisträger'
)
LIMIT 5
```

Edit: I found this link [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results) and the solution is similiar to @CSS

Comment: This only gives 5 results.  User wants 10 -- top 5 of each type.

Comment: Also notice it is tagged as MySQL, hence my most recent edit.

Comment: I noticed the mysql tage and added the LIMIT function @CSS

Comment: I added this article and I dont know if you had a look at it @CSS

Comment: I looked at it, but it doesn't support your original answer to *this* question. It supports an answer to a question that asks how to limit the query results total to a certain amount. Still not the 5 results per category that the OP wanted in the first place. I see you've changed it to mimic my answer. I must be right or something. =D

Answer (score 0):

This is the fastest way, do a top 5 on each category with a union and use that to select your data.  This method will work faster if you have good indexes.  You want them on page_id, cl_from, and cl_to.

Also note, I select only the page_id first before doing the union -- this allows a sql server to optimize performance.

```
SELECT * 
FROM page p 
join 
(
   select p.page_id 
   from page p 
   left join categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
   where c.cl_to = 'Art-Rock-Band'
   limit 5

   union

   select p.page_id 
   from page p 
   left join categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
   where c.cl_to = 'Echo-Pop-Preisträger'
   limit 5

   union 

   select p.page_id 
   from page p 
   left join categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
   where c.cl_to = 'Englische_Band'
   limit 5

   union 

   ...

   select p.page_id 
   from page p 
   left join categorylinks c ON p.page_id = c.cl_from 
   where c.cl_to = 'Rock_and_Roll_Hall_of_Fame'
   limit 5
) sub on sub.page_id = p.page_id
```

Comment: It returns a error "MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'" give it another way using union?

Comment: @Name - I re-wrote it as a join.

Comment: it just returns me 5 results not 5 of every category

Comment: @CSS it's "Server version: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)"

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM page p
WHERE p.page_id IN (
    SELECT c.cl_from
    FROM categorylinks
    WHERE c.cl_from = p.page_id
    AND c.cl_to IN (
        'Art-Rock-Band',
        'Echo-Pop-Preisträger',
        'Englische_Band',
        'Genesis_(Band)',
        'Grammy-Preisträger',
        'Peter_Gabriel',
        'Phil_Collins',
        'Popband',
        'Progressive-Rock-Band',
        'Rock_and_Roll_Hall_of_Fame'
    )
    LIMIT 5
);
```

Comment: returns 'This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery''

Comment: Also, if this one were to work, it would only return 5 rows, not the 5 rows per category the OP wanted in the first place.