# MYSQL-Error 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL-Query which have to go but it returns the error '`LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery`'

```
SELECT *
FROM page p
WHERE p.page_id IN (
    SELECT c.cl_from
    FROM categorylinks
    WHERE c.cl_from = p.page_id
    AND c.cl_to IN (
        'Art-Rock-Band',
        'Echo-Pop-Preisträger',
        'Englische_Band',
        'Genesis_(Band)',
        'Grammy-Preisträger',
        'Peter_Gabriel',
        'Phil_Collins',
        'Popband',
        'Progressive-Rock-Band',
        'Rock_and_Roll_Hall_of_Fame'
    )
    LIMIT 0,5
);
```

To explain what i want: I want just have 5 results of every category which is in the `IN`-Clausle.

MYSQL-Version: `5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)`

Comment: you can't use limits in subqueries: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html That's docs for 5.0, but the restriction is still in 5.7, so you're S.O.L.

Comment: Did you try my answer in your original post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770125/sql-set-limit-for-a-column/32770568#32770568 It shouldn't throw that error because there's no subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `IN` with subqueries which have an `limit`. The easiest (but maybe not the fastest - don't tested it..) solution would be to add a second subquery around the one with the limit, which have no limit.

So this:

```
field IN (SELECT ... FROM x LIMIT 5)
```

would become this

```
field IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM x LIMIT 5) temp_table)
```

In your case you would become the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM page p
WHERE p.page_id IN (SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT c.cl_from
    FROM categorylinks c
    WHERE c.cl_from = p.page_id
    AND c.cl_to IN (
        'Art-Rock-Band',
        'Echo-Pop-Preisträger',
        'Englische_Band',
        'Genesis_(Band)',
        'Grammy-Preisträger',
        'Peter_Gabriel',
        'Phil_Collins',
        'Popband',
        'Progressive-Rock-Band',
        'Rock_and_Roll_Hall_of_Fame'
    )
    LIMIT 0,5
) temp_table);
```

You could also try to transform your subquery in an inner join - that should also work.

Comment: You forgot to alias categorylinks with the `c` you prepend its fields with. I take it back, @name forgot to...

Comment: it returns after your alias edit the error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: @Philipp now it returns "Unknown column 'p.page_id' in 'where clause'". I really don't know why cause the page.page_id column exists

Comment: @Name, p.page_id belong to the table "page", you can't use it there : "c.cl_from = p.page_id"

Comment: ok that means there is no possible way to solve the problem :/?

Comment: I think, you dont need that part. just remove  `c.cl_from = p.page_id
    AND`

Comment: @Name: please check my EDIT

Comment: @Philipp, I think what Name wants is 5 "pages" for each "category"

Comment: As mentioned in my EDIT, if what you want is 5 results per category, I suggest you have a look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
it seems that your request has been misunderstood.

Even if there was no syntax error, the query you propose couldn't return 5 results per category.

To do so, I suggest you have a look at this post :
[Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

---

As per the error message, you can't use limits in subqueries.

You should consider using JOINS in your query instead :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM categorylinks c
JOIN page p ON p.page_id = c.cl_from
WHERE c.cl_from = p.page_id
AND c.cl_to IN (
    'Art-Rock-Band',
    'Echo-Pop-Preisträger',
    'Englische_Band',
    'Genesis_(Band)',
    'Grammy-Preisträger',
    'Peter_Gabriel',
    'Phil_Collins',
    'Popband',
    'Progressive-Rock-Band',
    'Rock_and_Roll_Hall_of_Fame'
)
LIMIT 0,5;
```

Comment: You forgot to alias categorylinks with the `c` you prepend its fields with. I take it back, @name forgot to...

Comment: It returns just 5 result. Not 5 results per category.