# How to select top N salaries for each person?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, cross-apply

I have the table

```
user_id  salary month
1        100    1
1        150    2
1        200    3
1        180    4
1        140    5
2        10     1
2        40     2
2        20     3
2        15     4
2        45     5
```

I want to select top 2 salaries for each people.

I try to understand cross apply. looks like my invented task conform the cross apply.

Now I have the following query

```
select distinct(s.user_id) from Salary s
cross apply (
     select top 2 * from Salary  sal
     order by sal.salary desc
)sal
```

look like I enough far from expected result.

expected result:

```
1    180
1    200
2    40
2    45
```

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OUTER APPLY with TOP 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            y.[user_id],
            d.salary,
            d.[month]
FROM YourTable y
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 2  *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE y.[user_id] = [user_id]
    ORDER BY [user_id], salary DESC
    ) as d
ORDER BY [user_id], salary DESC
```

Will return:

```
user_id salary  month
1       200     3
1       180     4
2       45      5
2       40      2
```

Another way:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_id] ORDER BY salary DESC) as rn
FROM YourTable
)

SELECT [user_id], salary, [month]
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Same output.

Answer (score 3):

You are close, just not selecting the right values:

```
select sal.*
from (select distinct s.user_id from Salary s) s cross apply
     (select top 2 sal.*
      from Salary sal
      order by sal.salary desc
     ) sal;
```

Note that a typical way of doing this would use `row_numbers()`.  I think the `apply` method may actually be faster under some circumstances.

Comment: can you shortly explain structure of query?

Answer (score 1):

Use Partition By and With Statement

```
Declare @SeriesNo INT=2

;With X AS
(
    SELECT
        UserId,
        Salary,         
        Month_Name,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY UserId Order BY Salary Desc) AS PartNo
    FROM @tblTest    
)
SELECT
    UserId,
    Salary,         
    Month_Name
FROM X
WHERE X.PartNo <=@SeriesNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT s.user_id, s.salary
FROM SALARY s
WHERE s.salary =
              (
               SELEACT MAX(ss.salary)
               FROM SALARY ss
               WHERE s.user_id = ss.user_id
              )
OR s.salary =
              (
               SELEACT MAX(ss.salary)
               FROM SALARY ss
               WHERE s.user_id = ss.user_id
               AND ss.salary < 
                              (
                               SELEACT MAX(sss.salary)
                               FROM SALARY sss
                               WHERE s.user_id = sss.user_id
                              )
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT 
                  user_id, salary
                 ,dense_rank() OVER ( partition by user_id ORDER BY salary desc) as ranking 
             FROM Salary) a
WHERE a.ranking <=2 order by a.user_id

Answer (score 0):

you can use query by using row_number()

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY salary DESC) rn
FROM salaries)
SELECT
    userid,
    salary
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query as well.

```
DECLARE @TopFilter AS TINYINT = 2;
SELECT  TOP (1) WITH TIES user_id, salary
FROM    Salary
ORDER BY (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY salary DESC) - 1 ) / @TopFilter + 1;
```