# How can I get fields from a non-generated, aliased table?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

```
Table<Record> myTable = DSL.table("myTable");
Table<Record> a = myTable.as("a");
Field<Integer> myField = DSL.field("myField", SQLDataType.INTEGER);

a.field("myField"); // == null
a.field("myField", SQLDataType.INTEGER); // == null
a.field(myField); // == null
```

I want to use a table expression in a comparison, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176977/618906). I am using jOOQ just to generate SQL strings; I am not using its code generation for my table types.

Answer (score 1):

I just now saw [this comment](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/aliased-tables/#comment-2073750696) in the documentation:

> A better solution would be any of these:
>
> ```
> Field MY_FIELD1 = field(MY_TABLE.getName() + ".MY_FIELD");
> Field MY_FIELD2 = field(name(MY_TABLE.getName(), "MY_FIELD"));
> ```
>
> I think that this section of the manual might be quite helpful for you: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/names

This worked for me, but I needed to make some changes because I'm using type-safe fields. I wrote this helper:

```
private <T> Field<T> field(final Table<Record> table, final Field<T> field) {
    return DSL.field(DSL.name(table.getName(), field.getName()), field.getDataType());
}
```