# Order by and Limit in a multiple table join using Group By to do a Limit by and Max

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, limit

```
Select group_concat(ID SEPARATOR '|') 
  from TableJ J
  Left Join TableL L on L.J_ID=J.ID
  Left Join TableB B on B.LJ_ID=L.F_ID
  Left Join TableLJ LJ on LJ.ID=L.F_ID
Group 
    by J.ID
```

The output returns records like

- 103237|43775|84462|19153|54618|108646|50142|96946|37251|75984|54524
- 29728|46758|65987|20772|34513|61323|2778|32630|53616|103450|27152|37278|65950|13837|33500|59490

etc

The issue is I need to limit the # of records/pipes in the results to 5 records.

In TableLJ there is a field `Population` which I can use to sort and limit but no amount of fiddling allows me to specify I want to Select the top 5 from that table PER group.

Update is that I can do the following to limit the group_concat (still does not solve getting them sorted first by LJ.Population)

```
substring_index(group_concat(ID SEPARATOR '|'),'|',5)
```

Comment: Hi. Select top n per group is a faq. (Obviously.) (It has a tag: [limit-per-group].) Please research before you consider asking. See [ask].

Comment: @philipxyObviously WHAT? I did research and asked it the way I could figure out how to ask it. Are you saying I should have KNOWN it was called ilmit-per-group or there was such a thing?

Comment: Hi. Re "obviously", it is obvious that a query with a straightforward meaning like that will have been asked many times. Re research, just googling your *clear* *specific* 'Select the top 5 from that table PER group' (without even 'sql' or 'site:stackoverflow.com') immediately returns answers. Re the tag, what I said was that it exists. I am telling you helpful things. See [help] links. In any case we don't need to agree. ('top-n-per-group' would be a good synonym--but one isn't limited to searching names of tags. LIMIT & TOP are synonymous keywords in different SQLs.)

Comment: [Here's my cut & paste for faqs. Clearly I think that askers (time & again every day) don't know & would benefit from at least some of it.] Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy I always do search google and here for my answers, thus you see fairly few and in-between (and relevant) questions. I did not find any answer that made sense to my use case and in fact still have not. I'll continue to google however

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2129693/3404097)

Comment: The google search I mentioned gives me [a question with 162 votes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/176964/3404097) with answers that work in MySQL 8.0 including a 16 vote answer that works in all MySQLs. But googling with 'mysql' gives the 303 vote proposed duplicate.

Comment: What (if anything) do you intend to do with the result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya 5.5.55-0+deb8u1

Answer (score 0):

- [`Group_Concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function has an optional `Order By` clause, using which we can sort the column value(s) to concat, based on another/same column(s).
- You can use [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to restrict the concatenated string to 5 per group.

Try:

```
SELECT Substring_Index(Group_concat(ID 
                                    ORDER BY LJ.Population ASC 
                                    SEPARATOR '|'), 
                       '|', 
                       5) 
FROM   TableJ AS J
       LEFT JOIN TableL AS L
              ON L.J_ID = J.ID
       LEFT JOIN TableB AS B
              ON B.LJ_ID = L.F_ID
       LEFT JOIN TableLJ AS LJ
              ON LJ.ID = L.F_ID
GROUP  BY J.ID
```

---

In [MySQL 8.0.2 and onwards](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/), we can utilize [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html), to determine [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number), within a partition for `J.ID`. We can sort by `LJ.Population` to get the row number accordingly.

Now, use this result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and consider only the rows upto row number 5. You can then do `Group By` and `Group_Concat()` accordingly.

```
SELECT   Group_Concat(dt.ID ORDER BY dt.rownumber ASC SEPARATOR '|')
FROM     (
          SELECT    J.ID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY J.ID
                                       ORDER BY LJ.Population ASC) AS rownumber
          FROM      TableJ   AS J
          LEFT JOIN TableL   AS L
            ON  L.J_ID = J.ID
          LEFT JOIN TableB   AS B
            ON  B.LJ_ID = L.F_ID
          LEFT JOIN TableLJ  AS LJ
            ON  LJ.ID = L.F_ID ) AS dt
WHERE    dt.rownumber <= 5
GROUP BY dt.ID
```