# Top-N per group (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, greatest-n-per-group

I have 10k - 1m goods wich are discribed by fields `product_id`, `name`, `category`, `price`. Which is the fastest way to fetched 10 most expensive goods from each category? Previously I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/176985/9513268.
My table:

```
-------------------------------------
|product_id| name | category| price |
-------------------------------------
|    1     |Phone | Gadgets | 599.99|
------------------------------------
|    2     |Jacket| Clothes | 399.00|
------------------------------------- 
|   ...    | ...  |   ...   | ...   |
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: So what was wrong with the answers there? Why didn't your attempt work? This feels like it's just a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @Larnu I thought maybe there’s a quicker way to accomplish the task.

Comment: Considering that the answer you accepted is the same as the answer you have linked, I've closed this as a duplicate of said answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions, as showned in the answer that you linked.

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by category order by price desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 10
order by category, rn
```

The key is to properly define the `over()` clause of the window function. You want the top 10 by `category`, so this column goes to the `partition by`; you want the top most expensive goods, so the `order by` criteria is on descending `price`.

You can run the subquery separately and stare and the `rn` column to better understand the logic.