# SQL: get top N for latest month and history for these

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I want to find the top N names (those with highest value) for the latest period. And for these names I want to get the historic values.

Per this question [Select top 10 records for each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have tried the following:

```
base_table (period, name, value)

CREATE VIEW TOP3 AS
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, COUNT(*) as rank
FROM base_table AS a
LEFT JOIN base_table AS a2 
ON a.period = a2.period and a.value <= a2.value
GROUP BY a.value
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
ORDER BY period, rank;
```

And this gets me the top 3 for each period.

```
period | name | value | rank
092020   Joe    100      1
092020   Jane   90       2
092020   Doe    80       3

082020   Jan    100      1
082020   Doc    99       2
082020   Pete   98       3
.
.
.
```

But not the desired result.

Let's say these are the top 3 for the latest month:

```
period | name | value | rank
092020   Joe    100      1
092020   Jane   90       2
092020   Doe    80       3
```

Now I want to get the history for these, even though they are outside top 3 previous month, like so:

```
period | name | value | rank
092020   Joe    100      1
092020   Jane   90       2
092020   Doe    80       3

082020   Joe    95       4
082020   Jane   94       5
082020   Doe    7        50
.        .      .        .
.        .      .        .
.        .      .        .
092019  Joe     42       20
092019  Doe     34       35
092019  Jane    1        100
```

FYI I am working in SAS, using PROC SQL, so niceties like CTE's, window functions and other stuff are not available to me.

Comment: What are those PERIOD values? What do 092020 and 082020 mean?  Are those supposed to be dates? Can those value actually be sorted as they are or do you first need to convert them into an actual date, or at least another string that sorts properly?

Comment: Only a fool stores a date as MMYYYY, as that latest date is not the highest valued date (122019 is a higher value than 012020). For the love of anyone that ever has to touch this data or code, use a DATE datatype or encode it as YYYYMM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*, ar.rank
FROM base_table a JOIN
     (SELECT a.value, COUNT(*) as rank
      FROM base_table a JOIN
           base_table a2 
           ON a.period = a2.period and a.value <= a2.value JOIN
           (SELECT max(a3.period) as max_period
            FROM base_table a3
           ) a3
           ON a3.max_period = period
      GROUP BY a.value
      HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
     ) ar
     ON ar.value = a.value
ORDER BY period, rank;
```

I suspect this would be simpler using a `data` step, at least for assigning the rank.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems it's still getting top 3 every month, irrespective of who is at the top for the last month. I have more experience in SQL rather than SAS-data language, therefore my first stab is in SQL. Also I want to make it a view so it updates dynamically.

Comment: @joddm . . . I see.  I added a new condition to get the results only for the latest period.

Comment: Unfortunately, the op has chosen to encode dates as MMYYYY, so MAX() won't get the latest period :(

Answer (score 1):

Can you try it with subqueries? if not you can create a view instead ordered with some row_number() / rank function to JOIN

```
SELECT b.period, b.name, b.value
FROM base_table b
INNER JOIN
(  
    -- subquery to get last period 
    SELECT TOP 3 name, period, value
    FROM base_table
    WHERE period = (SELECT MAX(period) FROM base_table)
    ORDER BY 3 DESC
) AS s ON s.name = b.name -- join them
```

Comment: Appreciate it, unfortunately neither TOP, row_number or rank are available in SAS' SQL implementation. Can't order by in sub-query either. So thats part of the reason I'm struggling here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would use SQL for this. Here is a method using OUTOBS option of PROC SQL.

First let's make some actual test data:

```
data have ;
  input period :ddmmyy. name $ value rank ;
  format period yymm7. ;
cards;
01092020   Joe    100      1
01092020   Jane   90       2
01092020   Doe    80       3
01082020   Joe    95       4
01082020   Jane   94       5
01082020   Doe    7        50
01092019  Joe     42       20
01092019  Doe     34       35
01092019  Jane    1        100
;
```

Now let's set N into a macro variable to make it a little more flexible. Since the example data only has 3 names let's use N of 2.

```
%let n=2;
```

So first find the top N for the most recent (MAX) period.

```
proc sql;
reset outobs=&n;
create table top&n as select name
  from have 
  having period=max(period)
  order by value desc
;
```

Now reset OUTOBS to MAX and use that TOPn list to pull all of the data from the original dataset for those names.

```
reset outobs=max;
create table want as 
select * from have
where name in (select name from top&n)
;
quit;
```

Let's look at the results:

```
proc print data=want;
run;
```

Which is:

```
Obs     period    name    value    rank

 1     2020M09    Joe      100        1
 2     2020M09    Jane      90        2
 3     2020M08    Joe       95        4
 4     2020M08    Jane      94        5
 5     2019M09    Joe       42       20
 6     2019M09    Jane       1      100
```