# How can I select up to [number] of items in a relation (SQL)?

Tags: sql, max

Let's say i have a store with some products in it. so my products are related to different stores. I want to filter 24 products, but max 3 products per store. Basically i can not return more than 3 products from the same store... How can i do that in sql ?

Comment: would be helpful if you will provide data structure/example

Comment: yeah, let's say i have
product = {
  id: string
  product_img: string
  store_img: string
  store_id: string
}
so i wanna bring 9 products and up to 3 products with the same store_id foreign key.
so if the query brings 5 products with store_id="store-id-1" the final result should show just 3, and then bring another 3 products with a different store_id.

Comment: check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product p1 JOIN LATERAL
    (SELECT TOP 3 id FROM product p2 WHERE p2.store_id = p1.store_id) p3
    ON p3.id = p1.id
```

Depending on your DBMS (e. g. postgre SQL, mySQL) you might need to use `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`:

```
SELECT id FROM product p2 WHERE p2.store_id = p1.store_id LIMIT 3
```

Oracle uses yet [another syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_top.asp)...

To get consistent results over multiple requests you might yet apply some ordering especially to the inner query, but outer one as well.