# Get the top record based on date and hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

My project has a table named CheckIns, basically containing all checking-ins performed by employees. Now I need to get 2 reports of the check-ins.

- First report: The total number of check-ins performed by day and hour
- Second report: The only check-in peak per day (ie. in what hour that most employees checked-in per day)

For the 1st requirement, I'm able to achieve it by using this query

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime) AS [Date]
    , DATEPART(HOUR, CheckInDateTime) AS [Hour]
    , COUNT(*) AS CheckInCount
FROM [dbo].[CheckIns]
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime), DATEPART(HOUR, CheckInDateTime)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime)
```

For the 2nd requirement, by adding `CheckInCount DESC` into the `ORDER BY` part, I got the hour that had most check-ins on top for each day, as you can see an example of 03 Jun (most of the checkins appeared to be between 8pm and 9pm, so 8pm - 20:00 is on top).

[image: sorted records]

However, this still does not satisfy the requirement, as it should only display the top peak record only for each day. Can someone please advise me on what to add to this query to achieve that goal?

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime) AS [Date]
    , DATEPART(HOUR, CheckInDateTime) AS [Hour]
    , COUNT(*) AS CheckInCount
FROM [dbo].[CheckIns]
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime), DATEPART(HOUR, CheckInDateTime)
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime), CheckInCount DESC
```

Thank you.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I think you can use the `Partition By` with `ROW_NUMBER()`, then select the records with row number equal to 1

Comment: Thanks @mtdot. I've managed to get the peak records. However, if there are 2 or more records (same day but different hours) that have the same CheckInCount number, I need to get them both, not just the first one.

Comment: If you are expecting ties in your dataset then use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`. `DENSE_RANK` will give same ranking to ties. In your case, records with same day and CheckInCount number will have same rank i.e 1.

Comment: Take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176964/select-top-10-records-for-each-category

Comment: [dup on MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/880812/sql-server-get-the-top-record-based-on-date-and-ho.html) and marked as answered

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this

```
with data 
  as (
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime) AS [Date]
    , DATEPART(HOUR, CheckInDateTime) AS [Hour]
    , COUNT(*) AS CheckInCount
FROM [dbo].[CheckIns]
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,CheckInDateTime), DATEPART(HOUR, CheckInDateTime)
      )
   ,ranked_data
    as (
select rank() over(partition by [Date] order by CheckInCount desc) as rnk
      ,[Date]
      ,[Hour]
      ,CheckInCount
  from data
       )
select *
  from ranked_data
 where rnk=1
```